# Vuejs, vuetify Data table how to make multi search value in 1 search box?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, datatables-1.10

how can make the search filtering by 2 or more columns ,
example searching for: first name and last name in the same query not only one of them.

Tried Adding custom filter but not working.

...

```
<v-text-field  v-model="search" append-icon="search" label="Search..." single-line hide-details></v-text-field>
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="theMainList" :search="search" >
  <template v-slot:items="props">
     <td>{{ props.item.id }}</td>
     <td>{{ props.item.first_name}}</td>
     <td>{{ props.item.last_name}}</td>
     <td>{{ props.item.phone}}</td>
   </template>
   <template v-slot:no-results> 
     <v-alert :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">No Search Result "{{search}}"</v-alert>
   </template>
</v-data-table>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
      headers: [{
          text: 'id',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'id'
        },
        {
          text: 'First Name',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'first_name'
        },
        {
          text: 'Last Name',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'last_name'
        },
        {
          text: 'Phone Number',
          align: 'left',
          value: 'phone'
        },
      ],
},
</script>
```

...

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom filters in Vuetify are currently broken: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/12136

Current's best solution is to filter the items (`theMainList`) yourself with a computed function.

Comment: was trying to avoid it since I have a lots of data around 5 thousand lines, any other suggestions?